# I-864EZ vs I-864: Any downside to filing the -EZ variant?

Tags: usa, immigration, financial

If an I-864EZ and I-864 are both applicable for your use-case, is there any reason *not* to use the I-864EZ? [I've read the *"Instructions for Affidavit of Support Under
Section 213A of the INA"*](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-864ezinstr.pdf),

- I meet the requirements under *"Who May Use Form I-864EZ?"*
- The guidance under *"When Not To Use Form I-864EZ?"* does not apply to me.
- I make over 120% of the poverty income number listed in the [I-864P, *"2022 HHS Poverty Guidelines for Affidavit of Support"*](https://www.uscis.gov/i-864p)

Is there any downside to using the I-864EZ form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I-864EZ is just a simplified version of I-864 for a subset of cases that meet certain conditions. If you meet those conditions, you can use either I-864EZ or I-864. There is no difference, except that the I-864EZ is slightly shorter.